# Node JS equivalent of this command using openpgp gpg --recipient <Hex_Key_Id> --armor --always-trust --encrypt test_pwd.txt; rm -f test_pwd.txt

Tags: node.js, gnupg, pgp, openpgp, openpgp.js

I'm trying to encrypt text using OpenPGP, but it is not similar to the value generated by CLI

Command:

`gpg --recipient <Hex_Key_Id> --armor --always-trust --encrypt test_pwd.txt; rm -f test_pwd.txt

Node:

```
const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey({armoredKey: publicKeyArmored}); 
const encryptedSecret = await openpgp.encrypt({ 
     message: await openpgp.createMessage({text: plainSecret}), 
     encryptionKeys: publicKey, 
});
```

Comment: `gpg --encrypt` by default compresses before encrypting, and with a named input file (as you did) includes the filename in the encrypted 'literal' packet; your nodejs does neither of those (although the README for openpgp implies it should do the first). Are either or both of those what you care about?

Comment: Which encryption technique is used by gpg --encrypt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the command to encrypt `gpg --recipient <Hex_Key_Id> --armor --always-trust --encrypt test_pwd.txt; rm -f test_pwd.txt`